# Are there available clothes models that fit MBLab models?

Tags: manuel-bastioni-lab, proxies

I just discovered the awesome MBlab project, but I still doesnt understand how clothing works. I read about proxy system, but I don't totally get it? Do I have to model the clothes manually and fit to the models? Or there are basic clothes model available for donwload that work together with these models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, you'll likely have to nudge a pre-modeled article of clothing  around your character manually.  That sounds more intimidating than it is, though, if you're patient, have experience deforming meshes, and are handy with proportional editing.

I think one process could be to give your  coat model, pants, shirt, etc, it's own armature with automatic weights and get it 90% of the way just through posing.  Bake it out once it's close and then tweak it with proportional editing (if it needs it).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is what I was afraid of. I wnated to use mblab to generate many characters (with clothes) programatically, but if I have to adjust the clothes it wont work for me sadly :(

Comment: I hear you.  You might try your hand at nudging vertices around sometime, though.  Super useful to be able to tweak models.  If you think the answer was thorough, click the check and help a new contributor get things started.   : )